mysql crc32() equivalent in postgres
Want to know if there is any equivalent existing function in postgres for CRC32()
I have below query, which works fine in mysql, but looks like UNSIGNED and CRC32() are not exists in postgres.
I thought of using sha256(), but it works only for String.
SELECT 
CONV(BIT_XOR(CAST(CRC32(PK) AS UNSIGNED)), 10, 16) PK_AVG, 
CONV(BIT_XOR(CAST(CRC32(X) AS UNSIGNED)), 10, 16) X_AVG FROM TEST_bigint ;

needed equivalent SQL for postgres.

Does this answer your question? CRC32 function with PL/pgSQL
